# Cursor Declaration Error

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I'm new to writing stored procedures. I have the following package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE STATUS_QUEUE AS 
    procedure get_errd (in_cd in char, in_sys in varchar2, out_info_cur out user_types.ref_cursor);
END STATUS_QUEUE;
```

and a package body of:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY STATUS_QUEUE AS
    procedure get_errd (in_cd in char, in_sys in varchar2, out_info_cur out user_types.ref_cursor)
       is dttmFormat varchar2(21);
    BEGIN
       dttmFormat  :=  common_functions.get_timestamp_format(in_stts_dttm);
       open out_info_cur for
    select email_frmt_name, bdy_text, sbjt_text, sys_id, crte_mdl_name, rtrn_email_addr_name, 
          to_char(stts_dttm, common_functions.get_dttm_pattern()) as stts_dttm,  stts_cd 
        from pih.email_last_status
        where stts_cd = in_cd AND sys_id = in_sys 
            order by STTS_DTTM desc;
   END get_errd;
END STATUS_QUEUE;
```

I receive the following error when I run it:

```
Connecting to the database hwvaldd3051.
ORA-06550: line 5, column 27:
PLS-00302: component 'REF_CURSOR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 16:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 21:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 11, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 20, column 20:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 20, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database hwvaldd3051.
```

The PL/SQL Block is:

```
DECLARE
    IN_STTS_CD CHAR(200);
    IN_STTS_SYS VARCHAR2(200);
    IN_STTS_DTTM VARCHAR2(200);
    OUT_INFO_CUR user_types.ref_cursor;
BEGIN
  IN_STTS_CD := 'ERRD';
  IN_STTS_SYS := 'jwg';
  IN_STTS_DTTM := NULL;

  JWG.STATUS_QUEUE.GET_ERRD(
      IN_STTS_CD => IN_STTS_CD,
      IN_STTS_SYS => IN_STTS_SYS,
      IN_STTS_DTTM => IN_STTS_DTTM,
      OUT_INFO_CUR => OUT_INFO_CUR
  );
  /* Legacy output: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUT_INFO_CUR = ' || OUT_INFO_CUR);  */ 
  :OUT_INFO_CUR := OUT_INFO_CUR; --<-- Cursor
END;
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error on the `Ref_cursor`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the type `SYS_REFCURSOR` as per the example below:

```
declare 

  recieving_cur sys_refcursor;

  procedure rc_test (out_cur out sys_refcursor)
      is    
  begin      
       open out_cur for
       select * from user_tables;
  end rc_test;

begin

  rc_test(recieving_cur);

end;
```